# Test Siebel Communication Driver using Communication Driver Test Engine

Tags: oracle, automated-tests, siebel

I have created a *Custom Siebel CTI Driver* that is working as expected in test environment. Before dispatching it to production, I want to load test *My Driver*. *Siebel* provides a standalone tool for testing named *Communication Driver Test Engine*. This tool requires a *Definition (`.def`)* file to load and use *Driver*. *Oracle* provides a sample *`.def`* [file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/CommSrvAdm/CommSrvAdm_DevDriver18.html) for default driver as example. I have run `CommDriverTestEngine.exe` providing this file and language code `ENU`. This starts agent and shows thread# for this agent. But after selecting other option it says `no active agent`. Snapshots for reference:[image: Test Engine]

Here is another one. When I select *Agent Definition* list. It views parameters from loaded *`.def`* file. Snapshot for reference:

[image: Test Engine]

Another problem is that `CommDriverTestEngine.exe` is not creating logs as described in def file. I have created a log file manually with same name in same directory with no luck. Same scenario is happening with *My Driver* testing. It starts *Agent* and shows Thread#, upon selecting option 4, it shows the definitions same as *`.def`* file. *My Driver* is not logging in its logs as well. Please suggest any fix.

**EDIT:**

[Same question at Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3985579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out guys. That was a trivial mistake. *Siebel `.def`* file contains *Driver Parameters* in following form:

```
[Profile:<driver-profile-name>]

   LogLevel = "True"

   Driver   = <driver-name>

   [Driver:<driver-name>]

      Library Name   = <driver-lib-path>

      Icon File      = <icon-file>

      Channel Type   = <channel-type>

      Channel String = <channel-type-string>

      [Driver Parameters:<driver-name>]

             Driver:ExampleDriverParam_1 = <driver-param-1-value>

             Driver:ExampleDriverParam_1 = <driver-param-2-value>

             ...
```

Note that this format states `[Driver Parameters:<driver-name>]` while *[Test Engine](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/CommSrvAdm/CommSrvAdm_DevDriver18.html)* states it as `[Driver Parameter]`. Also note that *Siebel `.def`* file contains `Library Name` in `[Driver:<driver-name>]` section while *Test Engine's `.def`* file contains `Library Name` in `[Driver Parameter]` section. So the correct *`.def`* file must be like this:

```
[Driver Parameter]

    Driver = <driver-name>

    Driver:LogicalID = <driver-logical-id-if-configured>

    Driver:CIMServer = <driver-cim-server-if-configured>

    Driver:CTCServer = <driver-ctc-server-if-configured>

    Driver:NetworkType = "ncacn_ip_tcp"

    Driver:SwitchType = "0"

    Channel Type = <channel-type>

    Channel String = <channel-type-string>

    Library Name = <driver-library-path>

    ...
```

Now configure `Job` and `Task` for an `Agent#` and we're good to go.